# How to use recursions with yield?

Tags: javascript, recursion, generator

Is there a way to mix the yield generator with recursions in Vanilla Javascript ?

I have a use case really close the the code below, please don't mind the async/await as there are promises in the original.

The issue is that the following example iterates only once.

```
let n = 0;

async function* atGet(offset=undefined) {
    if (n == 0) offset = true;

    if (n < 5) yield n;
  
    if (!!offset) {
        n = n + 1;
        atGet(n);
    }
}

const init = async () => {
    try {
        for await (let n of atGet()) {
            console.log(n)
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        throw err;
    }
};

init();
```

I'm wondering what I am doing incorrectly, any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) the call of the generator function as well.

```
if (offset) yield* atGet(n + 1);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the documentation link aswell